# Blackmagic Hyperdeck Recorder?

Tags: live-recording

I'm running an event next weekend and I'm in crunch time with planning. I've done dozens of these events but this is the first time I'm travelling so far to do it and with the clients equipment. I was thinking about purchasing a hyperdeck and a couple of 512mb ssds to record our event and make sure I've got a good high res version of the program feed. I've not used one and I'm wondering if I'm going to run in to any issues with recording in DNxHD on the device then editing on my win7 edit bay in premiere.

I was thinking about taking my atem studio to use a mixer (we're doing 2 or 3 cams and they already have an edirol hd mixer) then running program out of it, in to the hyperdeck to record, out of that in to my computer for final edit with wirecast and archiving it there and also putting it up on the video screen. Final destination is the web.

How can I add the live audio to the hyperdeck feed to archive as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your audio is coming over HDMI/SDI with your video stream there is nothing you have to do to record audio aswell. If audio is coming in separately you will want to use an HDMI audio injector or a more expensive SDI audio injector depending on what you use.

And no, there is nothing holding you back of using the hardware in the way you intend to. Though with every new hardware you take to live events, do a dry run before actually using it live and before driving to the event, or you can end up with a nasty surprise.

Comment: I'm going to try and use a bmd hdmi to sdi adapter I already have. It has hdmi in and 1/4 audio. It should be fine. I'll monitor the video and audio with a playback device. I am a little concerned with the audio sync. But I guess I can fix that in post.

Comment: Audio should be in sync unless you have a major delay between video capture device and audio capture device.